# Pagespeed + nginx + https - not minifying css and javascript

Tags: nginx, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I've successfully built nginx 1.8 full with pagespeed module.

I'm serving a Django app.

I see that line in the header: X-Page-Speed: 1.10.33.2-7600

But when I tried to hit my https website I see several css and js files loaded.

this is my nginx settings file:

```
    pagespeed MapOriginDomain "http://localhost" "https://example.com";
    pagespeed LoadFromFile "https://example.com/" "/path/to/static/files";
    # let's speed up PageSpeed by storing it in the super duper fast memcached
    pagespeed MemcachedThreads 1;
    pagespeed MemcachedServers "localhost:11211";

  # Filter settings
  pagespeed RewriteLevel CoreFilters;
  pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments;

  #  Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed
location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
    add_header "" "";
  }
  location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" {
  }
  location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" {
  }
  location /ngx_pagespeed_statistics {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }
```

What am I missing?
I also noticed this line in the header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
```

it seems that the cache is disabled and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I just missed the /static in:

```
pagespeed LoadFromFile "https://example.com/static/" "/path/to/static/files";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable client-side cache, you must set the Cache-Control headers, for instance like this:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|ico)$ {
    expires 1d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

Another trick to speed-up your site is disabling access_log and log_not_found for static content.
If you check your log I bet you will find many iPhone / apple specific fav icons hits that may result in HTTP 404

Answer (score 0):

try to add conf `pagespeed FetchHttps enable,allow_self_signed;` after line `pagespeed MemcachedServers "localhost:11211";`